# IoC, Multiple implementations of interface

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mef

I am making an application that communicates with a device. This can be done in multiple physical ways, i.e. serial port and network (single device on serial port, multiple devices on a network).

The ViewModels for each device needs the correct service injected into it.

So far I've only used one form of communication, so it was simple to have that single export for the interface. However, I've added one for serial port also now, and that's where things get a bit fuzzy for me.

The interface and implementations for the actual communication:

```
public interface ICommunication
{
    public byte[] Send(byte[] message);
}

[Export(typeof(ICommunication)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class SerialCommunication : ICommunication
{
    public byte[] Send(byte[] message) { .. }
}

[Export(typeof(ICommunication)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class NetworkCommunication : ICommunication
{
    public byte[] Send(byte[] message) { .. }
}
```

The "service", which has a bunch of methods for sending messages using an `ICommunication` and returning a reply:

```
[Export(typeof(IMessagingService)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class MessagingService : IMessagingService
{
    ICommunication _communication;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MessagingService(ICommunication communication)
    {
        _communication = communication;
    }

    public DateTime GetDeviceTime()
    {
        var response = _communication.Send(new GetTimeMessage().Serialize());
    }
    ...
}
```

A ViewModel which uses a service:

```
[Export(typeof(DeviceViewModel)]
public class DeviceViewModel
{
    IMessagingService _service;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public DeviceViewModel(IMessagingService service)
    { .. }
}
```

Earlier I just imported `IMessagingService` in the constructor wherever I needed it, and that worked great. But now that I added a second implementation of `ICommunication` this strategy failed.

During the lifetime of the application, it will have a single instance of `DeviceViewModel` which is used to communicate on the serial port. Other instances use the network service.

How can I solve this with MEF in the "correct" way? Should I model this differently?

Answer (score 1):

You can specialize your ICommunucation for Network and Serial communucations.

```
    public interface ICommunication
    {
        byte[] Send(byte[] message);
    }

    public interface ISerialCommunication : ICommunication
    {

    }

    public interface INetworkCommunication : ICommunication
    {

    }

    public class SerialCommunication : ISerialCommunication
    {
        public byte[] Send(byte[] message) { .. }
    }

    public class NetworkCommunication : INetworkCommunication
    {
          public byte[] Send(byte[] message) { .. }
    }
```